# Updating checkbox into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do i update checkbox value into database

```
$fmcourse = $_POST['fm_courses'];
foreach($fmcourse as $fmc) {
    $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["id"]);
    $sql = "UPDATE enrollments SET course_fk='$fmc' WHERE student_fk = '$studentid'";
}
```

`var_dump(fmc)` output this

```
string(2) "18" string(2) "20" string(2) "22" string(2) "24" string(2) "26"
```

When i update the course_fk repeats the same id on all the rows

```
+-----+------------+-----------+
| eid | student_fk | course_fk |
+-----+------------+-----------+
|  1  |          1 |        17 |
|  2  |          1 |        17 |
|  3  |          1 |        17 |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

I am looking for this

```
+-----+------------+-----------+
| eid | student_fk | course_fk |
+-----+------------+-----------+
|  1  |          1 |        17 |
|  2  |          1 |        20 |
|  3  |          1 |        22 |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: `$_POST["id"]` is an array of id's or single id?Also remove `'` quotes around variable in your query like this:-`$sql = "UPDATE enrollments SET courseid=$fmc WHERE eid = $eid";`(change studentid to `eid` in WHERE CLAUSE)

Comment: single id. studentid.

Comment: your shown table don't have `studentid `cloumn

Comment: edited the file. its the loop

Comment: I think you need INSERT rather than UPDATE. Check first for a duplicate before inserting a new record.

Comment: Now `courseid` is not present in your table

Comment: `var_dump output this`  var_dump of what?

Comment: Please clarify what you're `var_dump` is of, your code doesn't demonstrate that.

Comment: var_dump the `fmc`

Comment: You also need `eid` @Beekeeper. As your `student_fk ` value is repeated. It always update last value

Comment: @Beekeeper  is `eid` is an auto-incremented column?

Comment: Yes it is auto-incremented.

Comment: @Beekeeper  actually you need `eid` too for an update.Otherwise not possible

Comment: can you explain.

Comment: db data types of student_fk and course_fk?

Comment: for both it is `INT 11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below checks, using the function **record_exists()**, if the record has duplicates in enrollments table, if it has, then the code just updates the duplicates accordingly. If no duplicates, then it creates a new enrollment record for a student.

**Updated Code.**

```
$fmcourse = $_POST['fm_courses'];
    $student_id = $_POST["id"];
    $batch_id = $_POST["name"];
    delete_enrollments( $student_id, $batch_id );

    foreach($fmcourse as $fmc) {
        $course_id = $fmc;

        if( record_exists( $student_id, $course_id, $batch_id ) == FALSE ) {
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO enrollments (enrollment_id, student_id, course_id, batch_id, is_deleted, joining_date) VALUES( NULL, ?, ?, ?, 0, NOW() );");
            $is_binded = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iii", $student_id, $course_id, $batch_id);
            $is_exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
        else {
            undelete_enrollment($student_id,  $course_id, $batch_id);
        }
    }

    function undelete_enrollment($student_id,  $course_id, $batch_id) {
        global $conn;
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE enrollments SET is_deleted = 0, joining_date = NOW() WHERE student_id= ? AND course_id = ? AND batch_id = ?");
        $is_binded = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iii", $student_id, $course_id,$batch_id);
        $is_exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return $is_exec;
    }

    function record_exists( $student_id,  $course_id, $batch_id ) {
        global $conn;

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT COUNT(enrollment_id) as total FROM enrollments WHERE student_id= ? AND course_id = ? AND batch_id = ?");
        $is_binded = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iii", $student_id, $course_id, $batch_id);
        $is_exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return ( isset( $record['total'] ) AND $record['total'] > 0 );
    }

    function delete_enrollments( $student_id, $batch_id ) {
        global $conn;
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE enrollments SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE student_id = ? AND batch_id =?;");
        $is_binded = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $student_id, $batch_id);
        $is_exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return $is_exec;
    }
```

Comment: I have not tried Prepared Statement so far. Will try yours.

Comment: The record seems to update into the database, how do i remove the value from the database. If the user uncheck the option it should remove the row.

Comment: It works great. But i might have a issue the enrollment table has two more columns `batches` and `joining_date`. The joining_date takes the enrollment date and the batches works similar to the courses. I did not mention because once th course is fixed the batch column can follow the same pattern. The problem is uncheck the checkbox, the `eid` does not remove the row, it creates a new row with new id altogether. I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Where do you get the value for batches?

Comment: There are three pages, Student, Courses, and Batches. All the records are combined in the Enrollment page. One student can have multiple courses and batches. I am referring using the `eid` enrollment id and if the enrollment id creates new every time there's a update in the course, then it might create a issue?

Comment: I think, rather than deleting records, better to just add, in the enrollment table, a new field called `is_deleted` which has value of 1 or 0. We'll just change the value of that, rather than delete records so no new id's are created, rather their records just updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167926/discussion-between-karlo-kokkak-and-beekeeper).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your record according to `eid` not as `student_fk`

You also need `eid`. As your `student_fk` value is repeated. It always update last value

So your `where`condition have issue. You need to add condtion of `eid` instead of `student_fk` Also make sure `$eid` is difference for each row.

```
$sql = "UPDATE enrollments SET course_fk ='$fmc' WHERE eid = '$eid'";
```

Also your code is open for SQL injection. To prevent from this use **PREPARED STATEMENTS**

Comment: If the eid is different then how do you update the course_fk using student_fk. Lets say iam looking at `eid` 2, wouldn't that update only THAT row.

Comment: `eid` is different thats why you need eid when you have to update `course_fk `You also want array of `eid` to update multiple row

Comment: Can you please refer my first updated code. I have changed the eid.